# Statistical test to see whether we drew overly-balanced samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

I have an urn with $R$ red and $B$ black balls. $R$ and $B$ are large numbers. I draw some $n$ samples of different sizes without replacement until the urn is empty. The sizes of the samples are not a random variable, consider it a known determined value.

I want to see whether I am drawing samples that are more balanced for red and black balls than expected by chance. Which test should I use? I can think of tabulating the numbers and applying the chi-square or G-test. Usually, it tests whether my samples are overly biased, rather than balanced. So I should take the lower tail as the p-value in this case.

Is there a better or standard test for this that I should conduct instead? For my case, the sizes of each draw are small, say between 2 and 10. On the other hand $R$, $B$, and number of draws are large, in the thousands. I definitely don't want to program for combinatorial counting or p-value estimation by Monte Carlo simulations.

**Update:** So I tried to use R's `chisq.test` and `vcd::assocstats` for this, and there is no way to specify that I am interested in the lower tail. The statistics used for the two tests are $\sum_{i,j} \frac{(O_{i,j}-E_{i,j})^2}{E_{i,j}}$ and $\sum_{i,j} \log \frac{O_{i,j}}{E_{i,j}}$. They should be small when $E$ is very close to $O$.

Comment: Chi-squared test is goodness of fit test. If the test shows large p-value, it means there is no large deviation/"overly biased" observation (to use your terminology), hence "overly balanced". It is one sided and you can't take the opposite direction of the test.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. As noted, the Chi-squared test is traditionally a one-sided test on the upper tail. However, the Chi-squared distribution is two-sided, and it's possible to instead implement a one-sided test on the lower tail.

**Tables with fixed margins**

However, is the Chi-squared distribution appropriate in this case?

> I have an urn with R red and B black balls. R and B are large numbers.
> I draw some n samples of different sizes without replacement until the
> urn is empty. The sizes of the samples are not a random variable,
> consider it a known determined value.

Under the null hypothesis for an $r \times c$ contingency table, multinomial sampling and product multinomial sampling asymptotically leads to a Chi-squared distribution, but what is envisioned here is not multinomial sampling but hypergeometric sampling. As whuber notes below, given the dependence inherent in this sort of contingency table, i.e. the expectation for the $R$ and $B$ cells for a particular sample are conditional on the previous samples, it is not clear that the Chi-squared distribution obtains under the null in this scenario, and one might wonder about serial correlation (for references, see [Pesaran and Timmermann](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927074125/https://rady.ucsd.edu/faculty/directory/timmermann/pub/docs/test1.pdf)).

However, as far as I understand it, the scenario under consideration is simply a $r \times c$ contingency table with fixed margins and is identical to the motivating example offered by Alaouf (1987).

> Suppose N individuals belonging to c classes (ethnic  groups, for
> example) are hired for N summer jobs which fall into r categories.
> Both the number of individuals of each class and the number of jobs
> of each category are fixed. The hypothesis of independence in this
> context is the hypothesis that individuals are assigned to different
> job categories without regard to their class.

Substitute the c classes for $R$ and $B$ and substitute the r job categories of fixed size for the samples of fixed size.

For such a contingency table with fixed margins, under the null, the Chi-squared distribution does in fact obtain with degrees of freedom equal to $(c - 1)(r -1)$. For proofs, see [Alaouf](https://dx.doi.org/10.1080/03610928708829350) (1987) and [Cheolyong](https://dx.doi.org/10.1080/03610929508831514) (2007).

**Simulation**

While the exact details of the OP's case are not provided, we can provide a simple simulation to demonstrate how the Chi-squared statistics follows a Chi-squared distribution under the null.

```
n <- 1000
rs <- rep(10, 1000)
cs <- c(5000, 5000)

E <- outer(rs, cs) / (sum(rs))

set.seed(48)
a <- r2dtable(n, rs, cs)

sim <- 1:n

for(i in 1:n) {
  
  x <- as.integer(a[[i]])
  
  sim[i] <- sum((x - E) ^ 2 / E)
  
}

chi <- rchisq(n, df = 999)

ks.test(sim, chi)
```

The p-value for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is ~0.5.

Other simulations, however, demonstrate that contingency tables with a smaller number of observations may not approximate the Chi-square distribution. Thus, for the small table below, we utilize a simulated p-value.

**Implementation**

The chisq.test in R is a one-sided test on the upper tail, but a few simple modifications to the source code produces a function to test the lower tail. (The source code is available [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/chisq.test.R).)

```
chisq.test_lower <- function(x, simulate.p.value, B)  {
  
  nr <- as.integer(nrow(x))
  nc <- as.integer(ncol(x))
  sr <- rowSums(x)
  sc <- colSums(x)
  E <- outer(sr, sc) / sum(x)
  
  STATISTIC <- sum(sort((x - E) ^ 2 / E, decreasing = TRUE))
  
  if(simulate.p.value == FALSE)  {
    
    PARAMETER <- (nr - 1L) * (nc - 1L)
    PVAL <- pchisq(STATISTIC, PARAMETER, lower.tail = TRUE)
    
  }
  
  else {
    
    PARAMETER <- NA
    
    tmp <- .Call(C_chisq_sim, sr, sc, B, E)
    PVAL <- (1 + sum(tmp <= STATISTIC)) / (B + 1)
    
  }
  
  structure(list(statistic = STATISTIC,
                 parameter = PARAMETER,
                 p.value = PVAL))
  
}

environment(chisq.test_lower) <- environment(stats::cor.test)
```

Now let's say there are one hundred balls in the urn, 50 black and 50 red. We proceed to draw 10 samples of 10 balls each. We tabulate the samples to create a 10 x 2 contingency table. Suppose we ended up with 6 draws that included 5 red and 5 black balls as well as a few draws with 4 and 6 and 3 and 7.

```
x <- matrix(data = c(4, 6, 6, 4, 7, 3, 3, 7, rep(5, 12)),
            ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

set.seed(11)
chisq.test_lower(x, simulate.p.value = TRUE, B = 2000)
```

Simulating the p-value produces a p-value of ~0.06. Given that your urn includes very large numbers, this method should give you sufficient statistical power.

(Editing in response to feedback in the comments below.)

Comment: What is special about this situation is that the expected count at each step is *conditional* on the results of the preceding steps.  It is unclear that the usual chi-squared test applies or, when it does, what the degrees of freedom ought to be or what the expectations ought to be.  How does your solution address these issues?

Comment: @whuber, my reading of the question was that the OP wanted to carry out a Chi-squared test for each sample. (Of course after each draw, the expected counts would need to be adjusted.)

Comment: I think the key is the plural *samples* in "I want to see whether I am drawing samples that are more balanced for red and black balls than expected by chance." That refers to the entire sequence of draws.  There's also a multiple-testing issue to deal with.

Comment: @whuber, you are correct. Thanks for pointing this out. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: It's looking better.  However, there's a subtlety: the expected values in the table depend on the outcomes of all the preceding draws.  For instance, if by the time you have gotten the urn down to 10 balls, perhaps one is red and nine black.  You really wouldn't want to set the estimated counts at 5 of each, would you?  But that's what your code appears to do.  Moreover, the resulting distribution doesn't have the degrees of freedom you might expect ($n-1$) and often isn't quite chi-squared even.

Comment: @whuber, thanks so much for the feedback. The simulated.p.value in the chisq.test function neither relies on the asymptotic approximation to the Chi-squared distribution nor takes degrees of freedom as an input so I don't see any problems here.

Comment: You're correct that the expected counts are simply determined by the margins. Asymptotically, this is the expectation under the null hypothesis assumption of independence. I don't see how this case is different from any other contingency table with fixed margins--e.g. in the lady tasting tea example all but the first guess would also be conditional. I'd be happy to know if I'm missing something here though as this relates to a current research question I'm working on. Thanks.

Comment: It differs in several important ways.  One is that the values in the table are serially correlated, with negative correlation coefficients.  That's enough to raise significant questions about applying any version of a chi-squared test and raises doubts even about the simulation procedure. Another is that your chi-squared statistic looks like it leads to an inadmissible test: this is a technical term for a procedure that is inferior to another (using a better statistic) no matter what the underlying distribution might be.

Comment: @whuber, I've edited the answer again. Please do let me know if you think there are still issues here. And thanks again for all the feedback.

Comment: This is turning into a very good answer.  However, you appear to assert that this situation is an $r\times c$ table where *both* margins are fixed.  That's not the case: the margins: the crux my concern is that one of the margins is explicitly random, resulting from a series of draws without replacement.  (Correct) simulations of the process show that the distribution of your statistic is *not* chi-squared.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the feedback. Maybe I'm missing something simple here but my understanding is that both margins are fixed. The margins for the columns $R$ and $B$ are fixed as these are simply the total number of $R$ and $B$'s in the urn--as they are all drawn. And the OP explicitly gives that the sample sizes, which constitute the rows, are fixed. From your reading which margin is random?

Comment: Sorry; I had forgotten the details of this question.  The margins are indeed fixed, as you write.  However, I believe the simulation, the hypergeometric theory, and the chi-squared approximation all assume every possible configuration of the table is equiprobable.  I think this explains why the distribution of the chi-squared statistic under this sampling program is not chi-squared. We might differ here over whether to analyze the experiment as described or else to analyze the table *conditional on the results.* You are doing the latter, whereas I think the former may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks again @whuber. I'm still not entirely sure that I'm following this. What do you mean by "the distribution of the chi-squared statistic under this sampling program is not chi-squared?" As I understand the proofs, it should asymptotically be Chi-squared, and per my simulation, as long as n is large enough, it is chi-squared. (It does seem that n has to be quite large though.)

Comment: *Asymptotically* is correct.  The departure from asymptotic behavior for small $n$ (typically less than $10$) is strong enough to be of concern in this instance.  There's another concern: most of the results most of us are familiar with concern detecting extreme *departures* from the null behavior.  When it comes to assessing when the data look *too close* to the null behavior, we need to be careful about applying many of the familiar results: they might not hold.